# Firefox add on & react, how to access browser / content script

Tags: reactjs, firefox, add-on

I would like to use connection based messaging in a firefox add on.

React of course doesn't recognize `browser` e.g. `browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(connected)`.

On build react throws the error `'browser' is not defined  no-undef`

How do you access `browser` from the react app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add `/*global browser*/` at the top of your react js file.